# Giving Maximum Character Limits Per Line for TextAreas

Tags: javascript, php, css, textarea

I just tried to see how the data looks like on tables. I noticed that when it comes from the TextArea, the data does not contain any breaks on it, if you write several lines. I cannot set the width to the table. Nothing changes.

I think bringing the code wouldn't matter. It's a basic TextArea that we know. Just a little modifications.

So, I heard that it's possible using JS, but there should be a way in CSS too.(essentially, I dont know JS lang)

Here how it looks like:

http://i.hizliresim.com/LAjndo.png

Comment: Bringing code is always a good idea. It's not that we are lazy, but it helps us understand what is your problem. Just look at the answers now. One is php, second one is html, just wait and you will get javascript and css.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you could display the data using PHP's [wordwrap()](http://php.net/wordwrap) function. Example:

```
$text = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
$newtext = wordwrap($text, 20, "<br />\n");
```

This would automatically add breaks after every 20 characters.

If you add a the fourth, optional parameter, it won't cut your words in half.

```
$newtext = wordwrap($text, 20, "<br />\n", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

In html you can specify cols for characters per line, here for example 20

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="20">
Sample text
</textarea>
```